# Spark SQL: Get month from week number and year

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with "Week" & "Year" column and needs to calculate month for same as below:

Input:

```
+----+----+
|Week|Year|
+----+----+
|  50|2012|
|  50|2012|
|  50|2012|
```

Expected output:

```
+----+----+-----+
|Week|Year|Month|
+----+----+-----+
|  50|2012|12   |
|  50|2012|12   |
|  50|2012|12   |
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What about weeks that span across two months? Isn't week a weak variable to derive month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @zero323, who pointed me out to the sqlContext.sql query, I converted the query in the following :

```java
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

public class MonthFromWeekSparkSQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MonthFromWeekSparkSQL").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

        List myList = Arrays.asList(RowFactory.create(50, 2012), RowFactory.create(50, 2012), RowFactory.create(50, 2012));
        JavaRDD myRDD = sc.parallelize(myList);

        List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();

        // Create StructFields
        StructField structField1 = DataTypes.createStructField("week", DataTypes.IntegerType, true);
        StructField structField2 = DataTypes.createStructField("year", DataTypes.IntegerType, true);

        // Add StructFields into list
        structFields.add(structField1);
        structFields.add(structField2);

        // Create StructType from StructFields. This will be used to create DataFrame
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);

        DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myRDD, schema);
        DataFrame df2 = df.withColumn("yearAndWeek", concat(col("year"), lit(" "), col("week")))
                .withColumn("month", month(unix_timestamp(col("yearAndWeek"), "yyyy w").cast(("timestamp")))).drop("yearAndWeek");

        df2.show();

    }

}
```

You actually create a new column with year and week formatted as "yyyy w" then convert it using unix_timestamp from which you can pull the month as you see.

**PS:** It seems that cast behavior was incorrect in spark 1.5 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11724

So in that case, it's more general to do `.cast("double").cast("timestamp")`

Comment: In my case it is just incrementing the time without changing month and year. Please have a look at gist https://gist.github.com/nareshbab/7d945ccaaae07ca743dec0ea07bb50c0

Comment: You didn't copy the code correctly, so please review your code !